# File Transform Task with VueJS

Tags: vuejs2, azure-devops

I am setting up a VueJS app using Azure Devops to create build and release pipelines that creates artifacts to be hosted on Akamai NET Storage. Since I have 4 environments, I am looking for a solution that would manage the different API endpoints to be used in the app (One for each specific environment: dev, qa, staging and production). I have come across File Transform task (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/file-transform?view=azure-devops) that could be a possible solution for this, but I am not sure how to go about this with a VueJS app. If anyone has any insight on this, that would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> File Transform Task with VueJS

I am afraid you could not use the File Transform Task with VueJS.

Because the function File `transformations` of that task **only** supports for `XML` files and the function `Variable substitution` only supports for `XML` and `JSON` file formats. AFAIK, the configure file for VueJS should be the `.env` format.

You can check the [File Transform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/file-transform?view=azure-devops) task for some more details.

To resolve this issue, you could check if the method in following ticket give you any helps:

[How to use dynamic environment variables in VueJS](https://dev.to/djdany01/how-to-use-dynamic-environment-variables-in-vuejs-4l3e)